# Eclipse remove error text from code lines

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse suddenly started showing error text *within the code area* as an additional line. 
[image] 
I checked under `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors`, but there is no setting for that. 
I have no additional plugins installed. How to remove it? 
IDK, if this is an update or me changing appearance settings previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was added [in eclipse 4.1](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#show-markers-as-code-minings) and has settings in two places, one for general editors, and one for java editors:

- `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Code Minings`, then disable code minings
- `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors` then disable "Show code minings for problem annotations"

Comment: I see. So it WAS my fault. I changed it, didn't see immediate change an left it (dooh). Words "code mining" meant nothing to me. Huge thanks. I got unnecessarily annoyed with it :D